# Are Google Play reviews visible to all during staged rollout

Tags: google-play

With the staged rollout functionality, it became possible to have the latest version of an Android application available to a subset of potential users - anywhere from 5% to 50%. According to Google's documentation (link provided), reviews left during staged rollouts are public. Does anyone know if these are public to the entire Play store, or only public to other users inside the staged rollout audience?

We are planning on using it for a major feature-laden release, but are concerned about users seeing reviews talking about features that then don't exist for them (because they don't get into the staged group.) Want to know if Google manages versions and only exposes ones for the staged build to other users being offered the staged build.

Doc: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Per https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

> Users receiving the staged rollout can leave public reviews in Google Play.

So, the reviews by the people in the staged rollout are "public" but beta testers cannot leave "public" reviews. I don't know of any Google Play reviews that are not public - even to those that have not received the update yet. Even users that haven't installed an app can read reviews so the version installed by the end user is not relevant.

The slide from a Google Dev presentation also references public reviews by people receiving the staged rollout.

http://www.slideshare.net/PareshMayani/publish-latest-interesting-updates-android-dev

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, All review from any user which receive staged rollout or not are visible to all other users means if suppose user A received a staged rollout and user B don't received the update of staged rollout(still be at old version) and user A post a Review So it would be visible to user B and if user B post a review it would be visible to user A.

Suppose user A receive staged rollout update and user B don't receive update and it's still using the old version.

Another way of thinking is from complete Review Eco system So suppose user A post a review and that time rollout was 20%(staged rollout) So this review should not visible to user A(because he is not part of release(20%)) now developers increase the 20% in staged rollout and total percentage become 40% and a new user(who receive update in latest 20 staged rollout) post another review which should not be visible to user B. Now developer increase to staged rollout and change it to 100% So Now what should happened to those review which user post earlier when they receive staged rollout. So this way it's very difficult to manage that which review should visible to which user even in mean time they can belong to different version of App.